# I have installed a New Magento Theme but no products are visible as shown in the demo

Tags: theme, ce-1.9.2.2

I am using **Magento 1.9.2.2** and I have installed **Porto Premium Theme** as instructed in the [Porto Documentation](http://newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/video_guide/).

Their instruction was

> 1. Copy the following three (3) folders' contents: "Porto Theme", "Porto Theme (patch for Configurable Swatches)",
>      "Porto Theme (patch for Magento 1.9.2.2 and SUPEE-6788)" to project
>      root directory
> 2. Log in to Admin Panel
> 3. Flush Cache Management
> 4. System -> Configuration -> Porto - Settings Panel -> Theme Installation -> Import Static Blocks -> Import CMS Pages -> Import
>      Demo XX

When I refreshed the home page the theme was installed but the *categorized products* as shown in the demo of the theme were not visible.

What cannot I see just as like shown in the demo theme after installation of the theme to my project?

Comment: have you set Default Pages?

Answer (score 0):

because in demo theme the data base may differ from us. i think you should add products and category manually.

because check the back end catalog > products is there any products available or not.

> flush cache and re-index data it may cause issue.

for display on home page

Display All Products

To display ALL products, go to “CMS > Manage Pages” and select the homepage that you are currently using.

Code for displaying all products:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Display All Products From One Category

Go to “CMS – Manage Pages” and select “Home Page” from the list of pages.

Code for displaying all products from one category:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Then whats the point of buying a Magento theme like porto?

Comment: oh this is your decision to buy or not but related answer you should check. i hope you can understand and this will help.

Comment: and also theme provider always provide design not products and other things. we have to set up it manually.

Comment: When i am adding product category from admin panel, why it isn't showing to my homepage? What am i missing here?

Comment: check link http://www.aschroder.com/2009/10/3-easy-steps-to-add-products-to-the-magento-home-page-or-any-cms-page/

Comment: please check my updated answer to get products on home page.

Answer (score 0):

please set default page at

```
Admin-->system-->configuration-->General-->web-->Default Pages
```

i used porto theme.